# How to navigate other screen by declaring another class inside of the first class using react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm currently new here on this react native, I got confuse regarding switching my screen to another screen, I don't know why my import second screen not working when i click the onpress function declared to my first screen.,

```
import SecondScreen from './Screens/SecondScreen';


 export default class FirstScreen extends Component<Props> {


  render() {



    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

            <Header searchBar rounded>
                <Left>
                <Button transparent>
                  <Icon name='menu'/>
                </Button>
              </Left>
              <Body>
                <Title>Pay Bills</Title>
              </Body>

                <Item>
                <Icon name="ios-search" />
                <Input placeholder="Search" />
                <Icon name="ios-people" />
              </Item>
              <Button transparent>
                <Text>Search</Text>
              </Button>

            </Header>
            <StatusBar backgroundColor='#6633ff' barStyle='light-content' />

            <Text>How much would you like to pay?</Text>


        <View style={{flex:1}}>
                 <Image onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('SecondScreen')} source={require('./Assets/example.png')}
                   style={{flex:1,width:null,height:null,resizeMode:'cover'}}
                 />
             </View>

      </View>

    );
  }
}
```

As you can see I use the onpress function to navigate second screen.

```
onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('SecondScreen')}
```

My app.js file

```
    /**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 */

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, ScrollView, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import {createDrawerNavigator, DrawerItems} from 'react-navigation';

//screens
import LoginScreen from './Screens/LoginScreen';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android:
    'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
        <AppDrawerNavigator/>
    );
  }
}

const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    Login:LoginScreen,
});
```

How to move my first screen to the second screen using react navigation.
thanks.

Comment: you already used this.props.navigation.navigate() in onpress .. this is react-navigation property ...

Comment: yah. but the question is how can i move to the screen if i click the image?

Comment: is your code working or not ?

Comment: if it is not show your react-navigation configuration?

Comment: @sathishkumar not working, my screen is not moving to the screen if i click the image

Comment: ok show your react-navigation configuration ...

Comment: You need to add **createStackNavigator** into app.js

Comment: hi @VishalDhanotiya i already create drawer navigation. is that ok to create stacknavigator there?

Comment: Can you add drawer navigator code

Comment: sure i will. show my app.js file

Comment: You only add login screen you need to add all screen names on which you want to navigate

Comment: @VishalDhanotiya Question: I don't like to put the second screen to my drawer. how to do that,

Comment: I want the second screen as router only, not as drawer item

Comment: Then you to add **createStacknavigator** then add createDrawerNavigator in to stacknavigator

Comment: do you have example of that?

Comment: Ok i will share

Comment: Please check i have add a answer

Comment: yah thanks @VishalDhanotiya for the effort, i will try it first then if its good i will give you up vote for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some change in app.js. add createDrawerNavigator inside createStackNavigator.  Add those screen into stacknavigator in which you do not want to add into drawer.  In createDrawerNavigator add those screens in which you want to show in drawer.

Please check following code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  Dimensions
} from "react-native";
import { createStackNavigator,createDrawerNavigator DrawerItems } from "react-navigation";

//screens
import LoginScreen from "./Screens/LoginScreen";

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: "Press Cmd+R to reload,\n" + "Cmd+D or shake for dev menu",
  android:
    "Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n" +
    "Shake or press menu button for dev menu"
});

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return( <StackNav />);
  }
}
const StackNav = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Drawer: {
      screen:AppDrawerNavigator ,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerMode: "none",
        header: null
      }
    },
    First: {
      screen: First,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerMode: "none",
        header: null
      }
    },
   Second: {
      screen: Second,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerMode: "none",
        header: null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Drawer"
  }
);
const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
       Login: { screen: LoginScreen },

})
```

Comment: Error: says that the component route drawer must be react component

Comment: Pleaese remove export in fornt of StackNav i will update answer

Comment: I have made mistake use creatStackNavigator in place of stacknavigator

Answer (score 0):

pass the route of second screen also in  react navigation
then you can navigate to second screen

Comment: add details please

Comment: const MyApp = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
})

Comment: const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    Login:LoginScreen,
});
here you pass the second screen
Second:SecondScreen